# Advance Brain , Primitive Heart?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

This scenario keeps happening all around me. I find people very successful in their careers, great analytical abilities, wonderful problem solving skills, tackling pressure excellently, etc etc ..

But when it comes to relationships and matters of heart, they fail miserably .

Makes me wonder if only man's brain evolves and heart remains primitive for ever.

Is it ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't really address any topics of philosophy: it is at best  a question about psychology. (Perhaps you have been observing individuals who have spent more time contemplating and honing their technical skills than their understanding of relationships and social interaction, but beyond such speculation, this it is not something for which there is any sort of readily available answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enjoy [Romanticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism), which was in part a reaction against cold rationalism. You may also enjoy looking into [Existentialism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism), which has a bit of the same reaction element. I would characterize your observation as people being very good at identifying what *is*, but not so good at identifying what *ought* to be. The [naturalistic fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalistic_fallacy) states that *ought* cannot be derived from *is*, which might leave the strongly analytical mind floundering. The analytical mind is great at moving from known point *A* to known point *B*. But what about when *B* is not known?

Consider when a friend is having relationship troubles. What *ought* to be done? This has two basic answers. Under [emotivism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotivism), the answer is one's desire, perhaps modulated by others' desires. Under [teleological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology) accounts, there exists a *telos*, or final purpose, and the answer is whatever advances that purpose. One form of a *telos* is a [dikē](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dike_%28mythology%29), or 'social order'. Anyhow, if I am allowed to model some emotional responses as a comparison of the perceived *is* to the perceived *ought* ("I did X and he responded Z when he should have responded Y!"), then some of the counseling will be based on the counselee's perception of what *ought* to be.

There is also the issue of being able to get someone from point *A* to point *B* in sufficiently small steps. I claim this holds both in the intellectual realm and the emotional realm. How does emotional reasoning work? An example theory is [Spinoza on the Emotions](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/emotions-17th18th/LD5Spinoza.html). Some people appear to be natural at 'emotional reasoning' (feel free to come up with an alternative to 'reasoning'), while others find it very hard work. On the principle that it is increasingly hard to find someone who is an expert at 2, 3, ... things, I think it is natural that those with extremely high IQ would not have as high of an EQ.

Finally, I'm not sure your sampling of the population is very good. Are there "restorative forces" at play around you, which punish empathy? Examples are the idea that empathizing is weakness, that if you exploit people it hurts to empathize with them, not to mention the whole "not fitting in" factor.